# Adding nodes to a list in ascending order with Java

Tags: java, linked-list

Is there a way to use the compareTo function when comparing objects, I'm not sure if it's just for Strings. I am trying add an node into its correct position in ascending order.

heres where I declare my attributes/constructor

```
private Node<E> head; //refers to the head of the node
private int size; // keeps track of the size of the list

// default constructor which creates empty ordered list
public OrderedList(){head = null; size = 0;}
```

Heres my insert function

```
public void insert(Object o)
{
    Node n = new Node(o, null); // creates new node
    // Node for first element greater than or equal
    Node current = head.getLink();
    Node before = head; // Node for right before the next one is found

    // checks to see if list is empty
    if(size == 0)
    {
        head = n;
    }
    // checks if element is smaller than the head
    else if (o.compareTo(head.o) < 0) 
    {
        n.getLink() = head;
        head = n;
    } 
}
```

here is my node class

```
package project.pkg3;

public class Node<T> 
{
private Object data;
private Node link;

public Node(Object o, Node l){data = o; link = l;}

public void setData(Object o){data = o;}
public void setLink(Node l){link = l;}

public Object getData(){return data;}
public Node getLink(){return link;}


}
```

I'm getting an error message when trying to check whether the element belongs in the front on this line

```
  else if (o.compareTo(head.o) < 0)
```

telling me that it cannot find the symbol, which I'm not sure what that means

Im also getting another error message on this line

```
  n.getLink() = head;
```

this one is telling me that it's an unexpected type

Comment: `n.getLink() = head;` will never work. You are assigning an object to an expression.

Comment: okay.. can you give me a little more information? thanks @Jai

Comment: When you call `n.getLink()` it returns a Node, you ask it gives. You're trying to set .. it .. to `head` but that doesn't make sense. Maybe you meant to call `n.setLink(head)`?

Comment: yup that cleared the error with that line thank you! I'm still confused on the line where I use the compareTo function to check if the element should be put in front of the list. thanks again! @Matt

Comment: Have you implemented `Comparable` on your `Node` class? Some of the answers here illustrate how to do that. The reason you were getting a 'cannot find symbol' error is because you hadn't done that.

Answer (score 0):

Your node class should implement `java.lang.Comparable` interface and override its `compareTo()` method as per your logic.

```
public class Node<T extends Comparable<T>>{

}
```

Your argument object would implement Comparable interface. For eg:

```
public class Name implements Comparable<Name> {
  private String str1;

  public int compareTo(Name o) {
    //your logic here to compare object with itself
    return this.str1.compareTo(o.str1);
  }
}
```

Comment: The node just needs to define `T` as `T extends Comparable`.

Comment: now its telling me that it can't find the symbol for str1, should I initialize that as a variable? @z21

Comment: `str1` is a placeholder in this example code. You have your own class with its own member variables, you need to implement `compareTo` in a way that is appropriate for your class.

Answer (score 0):

If your linked list must be sorted using `compareTo()`, then you need to make sure that the underlying data is comparable.

```
public class Node<T extends Comparable> 
{
    private T data;
    private Node<T> link;

    public Node(T o, Node<T> l) { data = o; link = l; }

    public void setData(T o) { data = o; }
    public void setLink(Node<T> l) {link = l; }

    public T getData() { return data; }
    public Node<T> getLink() { return link; }
}
```

Then this block

```
else if (o.compareTo(head.o) < 0) 
{
    n.getLink() = head;
    head = n;
}
```

should be changed into this:

```
else if (
    (o.getData() != null) ?
    (o.getData().compareTo(head.getData()) < 0) :
    (head.getData().compareTo(o.getData()) > 0)
    ) 
{
    n.setLink(head);
    head = n;
}
```

I didn't look at your linked list implementation though, so I have no idea the other stuff are correct.